# Will appsync still request relationship if i don't request it in frontend

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm struggling to calculate the read capacity unit of a subscription (or query) when there's a relationship in my graphql schema.

Let's say I have 2 types which are connected to dynamodb tables:

```
type User{
   user_id: String!
   .... some user info
}

type Tweet{
   tweet_id: String!
   user_id: String!
   user: User
}
```

and in the resolver, I connected `user` in `type Tweet` to `type User` with `GetItem` operation.

My question is, when I query a tweet without user. e.g.

```
query tweet {
   getTweet(tweet_id: 'test'){
      tweet
   }
}
```

Even though I'm not requesting user field, Will appsync execute the GetItem operation to my user table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions do not read from your back-end data source; Instead the input of the mutation is forwarded to the relevant subscribers.

As for getTweet query, it's all based on how your resolver (mapping template) is set up. Your getTweet will only call the Tweets table unless you also write instructions to read the Users table (or the users record, if you're using a single-table setup).

Comment: for the query part, I originally use a single-table setup. Then I connected `User` to a user table in the resolver. So when I query `user` from `tweet`, it'll get the user detail. However, the question is if I **only query tweet (without the user)**. Will Appsync still executes `GetItem` on `User` table to fill the user attribute?